# Run two methods in a spring boot controller at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am spring boot beginner and I have a spring boot project which contain a controller and this controller contains two methods as shown bellow:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class Controller {
    
    @GetMapping("/preliminate")    
    public void OpentextWebService(){
        try {
            OTService.threadOne();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @GetMapping("/final")    
    public void OpentextWebService2(){
        OTService.threadTwo();
    }
    
}
```

the problem is that when I run : **localhost:8080/preliminate** and **localhost:8080/final** at the same time, only the first one will work. So is there is any way to run them at the same time?
I did some research and I found the @Async way but unfortunately I did not know how to impliment it in my code specially that I don't have a Service or Configuration Class.

Comment: Spring Boot is multithreaded by default. All requests to a spring controller goes through the DispatcherServlet, which is multithreaded. I am not sure why you mention that the methods are not executed at the same time. By default, spring beans are Singleton and will be shared across multiple threads - so is your controller. Put a System.out.print message before you call the OTService and you should be seeing that on the console. The OTService that is being used could be the limitation in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement this, is with @Async methods,
Create a Bean for you job Async.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class ApplicationRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRun.class, args);
    }

    @Bean("threadPool")
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        return executor;
    }

}
```

And then, create a service bean with a method like

```java
 @Async("threadPool")
public void asyncTask1(){
            OTService.threadOne();
}
 @Async("threadPool")
public void asyncTask2(){
            OTService.threadTwo();
}
```

And finally, call this service methods on your controller. Thats maybe works for you!

Comment: ok sir, thank you for the answer, but where do I put the Bean code exactelly ?

Comment: if you doesnt have a configuration class you can put in your main method. i`ve edit the answer.